# Wordpress Contact Form don't send files in attachment

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I've got a little problem with CF7. The plugin works good in wordpress, but when I put the file field on the form, the wordpress doesn't send the e-mail, if I take off the file field, it works perfectly.

**EDIT -----------**

**Form HTML:**

```
<div class="row-fluid formulario-cotacao">
     <div class="span12">
          <h3>Seus Dados de Contato</h3>
          [text* your-name watermark "Nome:"]
          [email* your-email watermark "E-mail:"]
          [tel* tel-987 id:telId class:telClass watermark  "Telefone:"]

          [textarea your-message watermark "Mensagem:"]
     </div>
     <div class="span12">
          <h3>Tipo de Seguro Desejado</h3>
          [checkbox* tipo-seguro id:tipo-seguro class:tipo-seguro label_first use_label_element "seguro de automóvel" "seguro de motos" "consórcio" "seguro de vida" "planos de saúde" "seguro de caminhões" "seguro prestamista" "carta verde" "previdência privada" "seguro viagem"]

     </div>
<div class="span12">
          [text outros id:outros class:outros watermark  "Outros Seguros Desejados:"]
</div>

<div class="span12">
          <p>Enviar arquivo</p>
          <p>[file arquivo limit:3000000 filetypes:jpg|doc|png|pdf id:arquivo class:arquivo]</p>
</div>
          <p class="text-center">[submit id:cotar class:cotar "solicitar cotação"] <input type="reset" value="limpar campos" /> </p>


</div>
```

**IN MESSAGE BODY:**

```
<h1 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; color:#06F;">Cotação do Web Site</h1>
<p><b>Nome: </b><br/>          [your-name]</p>
<p><b>E-mail: </b><br/>          [your-email]</p>
<p><b>Telefone: </b><br/>          [tel-987]</p>
<p><b>Mensagem: </b><br/>         [your-message]</p>
<p><b>Outros seguros desejados: </b> <br/>         [outros]</p>
<p><b>Arquivo:</b> <img src="[arquivo]"> <br> [arquivo]</p>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<h3 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; color:#06F;">
       <b>Tipo de Seguro Desejado</b>
</h3><br/>

<p> [tipo-seguro]</p>
```

**IN ATTACHMENT FIELD:**

```
[arquivo] // <-- this is my input file field
```

Someone already had the same problem?

Comment: Please add the relevant code, in this case the form definition

Comment: Look,I put  the codes in the question

Comment: Try removing it from the message, i don't think you can embed them directly there.

Comment: It is removed from message body, I put him only in attachment field